# HTACCESS 301 Redirect Rule to point all URL Variations to the Live URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, redirect

I am trying to achieve something which is working 99%, but there is a tiny issue.

Let's say my live URL is https://www.example.com/sample-page/

I want all the following URL variations to redirect to the live URL with a 301 status.

```
http://example.com/sample-page/
http://www.example.com/sample-page/
https://example.com/sample-page/
```

All of the above should redirect to https://www.example.com/sample-page/

I managed to get this working by using the htaccess rule displayed below.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The problem with the above rule is this: http://example.com/sample-page/ does a double redirect.

```
http://eyeacademy.com/expert-eye-examination/
301 Moved Permanently
https://eyeacademy.com/expert-eye-examination/
301 Moved Permanently
https://www.eyeacademy.com/expert-eye-examination/
200 OK
```

As you can see, http redirects to https and then https non-www redirects to https www. I have been trying a few tweaks to this rule and reading up, but I am sure someone here would have a quicker and more robust solution?

Comment: Put the https rule last?

Comment: Tried that. It breaks https non-www URLs by adding www.www. to the domain.

Comment: Take `L` last off the first rule.

Comment: @123 taking L off works for everything expect
http:// www.eyeacademy.com/about-us/ redirects to https:// www.eyeacademy.com/ and not https:// www.eyeacademy.com/about-us/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this single rule to redirect `http -> https` and add `www` and there is no need to hardcode host name in the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

You can also reorder your existing rules and avoid multiple redirects like this:

```
# first add www and make sure it is https://
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# http -> https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks. The first option works. I'll try the second one too.

Comment: [See this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and heading **Non-Capturing Groups**

Answer (score 1):

Use an `or` flag in your `RewriteCond` directive. Replace everything with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The solution proposed should be `HTTP_HOST` agnostic

Comment: @freedev Why? The OP has not mentioned such a requirement. Anyways, a generic redirection shouldn't be hard to achieve either.

Comment: @hjpotter it would be wise to not hardcode the domain name. e.g. There might be two domains pointing to the same folder i.e. Magento multi-sites